# Iterate through div in selenium(python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hi I am making scraper in selenium using python. The structure of a web:

[image]

I want to get all the prices and a day. But I am not even able to catch a div as a iterable object as the code below return TypeError "object not interable"...:

```
months = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='departure-calendar']")
for day in months:
    daily_price=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='value']")
    print(daily_price.text)
```

What am i doing wrong? I spend few hours looking for an answer to my problem but couldn't find. Thanks in advance for any help.

//EDIT
Thanks to @xxMrPHDxx
It's woking!

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='value']")    
for p in prices:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `months`, you would probably want `find_elements_by_xpath` function instead that returns a list

Comment: I don't understand. I am using find_elements_by_xpath function.